# Maximum Flow GPU implementation

Tags: gpu, max-flow

Is there any library/framework that provides a "SOTA" GPU implementation of a maximum flow algorithm? I found [this presentation](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2017/presentation/S7370-hugo-braun-efficient-maximum-flow_algorithm.pdf) by some NVIDIA engineers but I cannot find any related implementation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/PratyushVM/maxflow-cuda) implementation by [PratyushVM](https://github.com/PratyushVM). Hope this resolves your query :)